# How can I seperate the common steps class and the step definitions class in Cucumber, TestNg?

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, testng, bdd

I want to ask like if I have the step definition class GithubHomePageSteps.java corresponding to the feature file  GithubHomePage.feature and the common steps class CommonSteps.java in the same package called steps then how do I run the test cases.

Here in the common steps class I have say the chrome driver initialization in the setUp() and quitting of the chrome driver method in the clean(). I have put the @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite annotation before the setUp() and the clean() repectively.

I have also created the testng.xml (where I have included these two classes CommonSteps and GitHubHomePageSteps) and the TestRunner class in a package called runner. When I try to run the test using the testng.xml file by running as TestNg Suite I get the TestNgException can't instantiate the class GithubHomePageSteps. Can someone help me?

```
testNg.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="steps.GithubHomePageSteps"/>
      <class name="steps.CommonSteps"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

TestRunner.java:
package runner;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = "steps",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/json-report/cucumber.json"},
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = true
)

@Test
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the steps definition classes in glue like below :

glue = {
"com/arb/aut/Login/StepDefinitions", "com/arb/aut/Dashboard/StepDefinitions",
"com/arb/aut/Cards/StepDefinitions",
"com/arb/aut/Hooks" }